# Group items by common property in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm looking for an efficient way to rearrange an array of objects in JS. I need to combine two parameters from each object into a single object, where the `gwdetailsid` value is the same.

Initial array:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "gwdetailsid": "gw1",
      "gwpname": "username",
      "gwpvalue": "transalis"
    },
    {
      "gwdetailsid": "gw1",
      "gwpname": "password",
      "gwpvalue": "secure_password@1"
    },
    {
      "gwdetailsid": "gw2",
      "gwpname": "username",
      "gwpvalue": "tesco"
    },
    {
      "gwdetailsid": "gw2",
      "gwpname": "password",
      "gwpvalue": "lemon_farmer_2"
    }
  ]
}
```

The desired output array:

```
{
  "gateways": [
    {
      "gwdetailsid": "gw1",
      "username": "transalis",
      "password": "secure_password@1"
    },
    {
      "gwdetailsid": "gw2",
      "username": "tesco",
      "password": "lemon_farmer_2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are you benchmarking your solution?

Comment: `efficient way to rearrange an array of objects in JS`. Please post the code that you have attempted, so that we will make that efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, your task comes down to transforming `data` array into `gateways` array.

You may employ [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for that kind of job, to build up the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) with `gwdetailsid` property as a key, then extract [`.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) of that `Map`:

```js
const data = [{gwdetailsid:"gw1",gwpname:"username",gwpvalue:"transalis"},{gwdetailsid:"gw1",gwpname:"password",gwpvalue:"secure_password@1"},{gwdetailsid:"gw2",gwpname:"username",gwpvalue:"tesco"},{gwdetailsid:"gw2",gwpname:"password",gwpvalue:"lemon_farmer_2"}],
      
      gateways = [...data
        .reduce((acc, {gwdetailsid, gwpname, gwpvalue} ) => {
          const group = acc.get(gwdetailsid)
          group
            ? group[gwpname] = gwpvalue
            : acc.set(gwdetailsid, {gwdetailsid, [gwpname]: gwpvalue})
          return acc
        }, new Map)
        .values()
      ]
      
console.log(gateways)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```